# Variance of the sample variance for dependent data

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence, variance

When the random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d., then the sample variance $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2$

has the variance

$\frac{\mu_4}{n} - \frac{ \sigma^4(n-3)}{n(n-1)}$

where $\mu_4$ is the fourth central moment of $X_1$ and $\sigma^2$

is the variance.

What is the sample variance if the variables 
$X_1,...,X_n$
are dependent (e.g. ARMA(p, q)-process)? Are there some results?